# Como passar um valor de um QDialog para a MainWindow PySide6

Tags: dialog, pyside

Preciso de uma ajuda, já tenho a cabeça a deitar fumo e não consigo entender a lógica de passar valores de um QDialog para a MainWindow.

O erro é:

```
AttributeError: 'Ui_Dialog' object has no attribute 'txtrec'
```

Ele vai assumir o Ui_Dialog, por causa do "self", mas se não colocar depois não acedo ao á label que está no self.ui

Este é o código que tenho:

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QMainWindow, QPushButton
from ui_main import Ui_MainWindow
from ui_dialog import Ui_Dialog

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    """Main window."""
    def __init__(self):
        """Initializer."""
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.secondwindowshow)

    def up(self,txt):
        self.ui.txtrec.setText(txt)

    def secondwindowshow(self):
        txt = self.ui.lineEdit.text()
        vars=txt
        x=secondwindow(vars)
        x.exec()

class secondwindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self,txt):
        """Initializer."""
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.label.setText(txt)
        for i in range(50):
            self.ui.comboBox.addItem(str(i))
        self.ui.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.go)
        self.ui.buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.gonot)

    def go(self):
        vars=self.ui.comboBox.currentText()
        MainWindow.up(self,vars)
        print(vars)
        self.close()
        w.show()

    def gonot(self):
        print ('nok')
        self.close()

# Create the application
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
w.show()
app.exec()
```

PS:eu tenho de enviar um valor da MainWindow para o dialog, e depois enviar outro de volta do combobox para a MainWindow , se houver uma maneira mais simples por favor me expliquem

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: não sei como ser mais especifico, preciso passar um valor do combobox do dialog, para um editline na mainwindow, mas nao consigo acesso aos elementos do ui